# Is MD5 supported on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, md5

I'm porting some compact framework code that consumes a RESTful service to Windows Phone 7. The REST service requires md5 hashing and method signatures.

This code (which worked on NETCF) no longer compiles and I don't see anything MD5 related in the object browser.

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
buffer = md5.ComputeHash(buffer);
```

Is md5 not supported on WP7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick googling reveals that some cryptography classes are not supported in any Silverlight versions. One of these is MD5CryptoServiceProvider.

You can use [this MD5 implementation for Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5) on Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

[AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28VS.95%29.aspx) is supported on Phone 7.  If you need MD5, you need to look [elsewhere](http://bouncycastle.org/).